# Cron Job not working in cpanel

Tags: mysql, cron, yii

I have setting a cron job in yii console mode. Where I have tried the following from localhost which work successfully.where the code for **Gocommand.php** is

```
class GoCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args)
    {
        //echo "hello";
        $counter = Cron::model()->findByPk(1);
        $counter->val = $counter->val + 1;
        $counter->save(false);     }
}
```

which increase the value after giving command `path/to/project/protected yiic Go`. which update the database. But I tried the same in cpanel by giving the following command
`/usr/sbin/php /home/funwork/public_html/crontab/protected/yiic Go` . Rest are same. Why is it not working.Can anyone have some solution. 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Is there an error message? Try this. `/usr/sbin/php  /home/funwork/public_html/crontab/protected/yiic Go >> output.txt 2>&1`. Then check the file. You can also set up cron jobs to notify you via an email if there are errors.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a `console.php` file next to index.php file.

And you need to use that, and not yiic, since that is in protected, and you might have no access to it.

I have a cron setup like this:

```
10 2 * * 7 cd /var/www/web13/web; /bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/php console.php forceinstance ro DocumentationHealthMonitor DetectMaxStorageSpaceReached --alert_size_gb=400 2>&1
```